# Failed to concatenate global layer netCDF data using NCO

Tags: netcdf, nco

I am using monthly global potential evapotranspiration data from [TerraClimate](http://www.climatologylab.org/terraclimate.html) from 1958-2020 (available as 1 nc per year) and planning to concatenate all into single nc file.
The data has a variable `pet` and three dimension `ppt(time,lat,lon)`.

I managed to combine all of the data using `cod mergetime TerraClimate_*.nc` and generate around 100GB of output file.

For analysis purpose in Windows machine, I need single netCDF file with order `lat,lon,time`. What I have done is as follows:

1. Reorder the dimension from `time,lat,lon` into `lat,lon,time` using `ncpdq` command

```
for fl in *.nc; do ncpdq -a lat,lon,time $fl ../pet2/$fl; done
```

2. Loop all file in the folder to make time the record dimension/variable used for concatenating files using `ncks` command

```
for fl in *.nc; do ncks -O --mk_rec_dmn time $fl $fl; done
```

3. Concatenates all nc files in the folder into one nc file using `ncrcat` command

```
ncrcat -h TerraClimate_*.nc -O TerraClimate_pet_1958_2020.nc
```

It's worked, but the result is not what I expected, it generate 458KB size of file, when I check the result using Panoply it provide wrong information, all have value -3276.7. See below picture.

[image: Panoply]

I have check the files from step 1 and 2, and everything is correct.

I also try to concatenate only 2 files, using [1958](http://thredds.northwestknowledge.net:8080/thredds/fileServer/TERRACLIMATE_ALL/data/TerraClimate_pet_1958.nc) and [1959](http://thredds.northwestknowledge.net:8080/thredds/fileServer/TERRACLIMATE_ALL/data/TerraClimate_pet_1959.nc) data (each file 103MB), but the result still not what I expected.

```
ncrcat -h TerraClimate_pet_1958.nc TerraClimate_pet_1959.nc -O ../TerraClimate_pet_1958_1959.nc
```

Did I missed something on the code or write the wrong code? Any suggestion how to solve the problem?

UPDATE 1 (22 Oct 2021):

Here's the metadata of original data downloaded from above link.
[image: metadata]

UPDATE 2 (23 Oct 2021):

Following suggestion from Charlie, I did unpack for all the data from point 2 above using below command.

```
for fl in *.nc4; do ncpdq --unpack $fl ../unpack/$fl; done
```

Here's the example metadata from unpack process.

[image: metadata unpack]

And the data visualised using Panoply.

[image: unpack panoply]

Then I did test to concatenate again using 2 data from unpack process (1958 and 1959)

```
ncrcat -h TerraClimate_pet_1958.nc TerraClimate_pet_1959.nc -O ../TerraClimate_pet_1958_1959.nc
```

Unfortunately the result remain same, I got result with size 1MB. Below is the metadata

[image: ncrcat metadata]

And visualised the ncrcat result using Panoply

[image: ncrcat panoply]

Answer (score 0):

Your commands appear to be correct, however I suspect that the data in the input files is packed. As explained in the `ncrcat` documentation [here](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncrcat), the input data should be unpacked (e.g., with `ncpdq --unpack`) prior to concatenating all the input files (unless they all share the same values of `scale_factor` and `add_offset`). If that does not solve the problem, then (1) there is likely an issue with `_FillValue` and (2) please post the `pet` metadata from a sample input file.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question and adding the metadata screenshot of the original pet.

Comment: The data are indeed packed. As my answer recommends, first unpack them then concatenate them.

Comment: Ok, I have test to unpack for 1 data `ncpdq --unpack TerraClimate_pet_1958.nc ../TerraClimate_pet_1958.nc`, and worked. Before I continue, please advise on: Which data should I unpack? the original data? or data from point 2 result in my question above?

Comment: Either one it does not matter. Just do it before ncrcat.

Comment: I have update the progress in my question above following your suggestion to unpack, then do concatenate using ncrcat. Unfortunately the result remain same. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure what's happening. You appear to be mixing the positional arguments with the options. Try unmixing them like this: ncrcat -O -h TerraClimate_pet_1958.nc TerraClimate_pet_1959.nc ../TerraClimate_pet_1958_1959.nc

Comment: I did it, but still failed. I also try to unpack the original data, then reorder the dimension to `lat,lon,time`, follow with fix lat dimension who become unlimited, make time dimension unlimited again, finally concatenate. And failed again.

Comment: But if I do concatenate using original data (`time,lat,lon`), the result is perfect. The only problem is concatenate data with (`lat,lon,time`), seems not possible.

Comment: I think I understand what happened. Apparently ncrcat insists that the concatentation dimension be the first dimension, even though netCDF4 does not impose this constraint. And all the files use the same packing attributes (I presume) so it's OK to just run ncrcat all the input files without unpacking them first. Then you can use ncpdq on the aggregated file if you want.

Comment: Yes its worked for `ncrcat`. But reordering dimension from `time,lat,lon` to `lat,lon,time` using `ncpdq` still failed for nc files with 7GB generated from NCO and around 100GB if using `cdo mergetime` (monthly global data, 4km spatial res, 1958-2020).

Comment: The most likely region ncpdq fails is due to insufficient RAM. It keeps two buffers of the whole file in memory while it permutes the indices. Try it on a machine with ~200 GB RAM.